# Access 2D array slots by a number and vice versa

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

I want to map an array indices to a number, if this is an array:

```
grid2=[ ['a','b','c'],
        ['x','y','z']]
```

the number of 'a' is 1 and the number of 'b' is 2 and the number of 'c' is 3 and the number of 'x' is 4 and the number of 'y' is 5 and the number of 'z' is 6.
Here is my attempt, but it works only for squared arrays:

```
def i2d(r,c):
    return r*height + c+1
```

here is the result which is not correct:

```
slot number  of a=1  slot number of b=2 slot number of c=3
slot number  of x=6  slot number of y=7 slot number of z=8
```

**the correct result should be:**

```
slot number  of a=1 slot number of b=2 slot number of c=3
slot number  of x=4 slot number of y=5 slot number of z=6
```

Also I want to write a convert method for mapping an integer to array index, here is my attempt:

```
def d2i(d):
    r= int(d/height)-1
    c= width - r
    return (r,c)
```

but unfortunately, the final output is not correct. please help me in writing these two functions, I don't why my algorithm development aspect is turned off, maybe it is a side effect of using frameworks and libraries that they do the logic behind the scene, and I have used to call them.

Please tell me about the pythonish code if python has solved this by one of its operators or library functions, I want to learn it if such a thing exists.

**Example : (input/output)**

```
grid=                 [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
#desired slot numbers=[1   ,2  ,3     ,4  ,5   ,6]
x = i2d(0,2) 
#so x would be 3 if the we suppose number of a is 1
slot = d2i(3)
row=slot[0]
col=slot[1]
print(grid[row][col])
#the output is 'c'
```

Thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

I think calculation  the slot number for an array index has different formula for when W=H and W>H and W<H:

```
def i2d(r,c,w,h):
    if(h>w):
        return r*h + c-r+1
    if(h==w):
        return r*h+c+1
    if(h < w):
        return r * w + c + 1
```

Comment: what is `r` and `c` and where do you get `height` from?

Comment: r is row index and c is column index and width and height are the size of the array that are defined globally.

Comment: Can we assume that width's are the same?

Comment: can you please give a standard input and an expected output from each function

Comment: I've write the example in the post

Comment: @Basto please check the question again, I've updated it

Comment: Not sure why (0, 2) should be 3? Can you expound on that pls

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Think 2D array as linear list, the number corresponding to (0,2) is 3 if the first element number supposed to be 1.

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid I think your examples are contradicting each other. In your example, output from `i2d` has `x = 4`, but your example output at the end of the post has `x = 3`. I assume `x = 4` is correct based on the other text.

Comment: @LaytonGB please check the example again, it has been updated

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid Right underneath your update you have this written: `#so x would be 3 if the we suppose number of a is 1`

Comment: @LaytonGB output from i2d is 3 is you set height=3 (size of each array in the grid array)

Comment: @Basto agreed, but that shouldn't be the value for `'x'` that should be the value for `'c'` based on all other information in the post.

Comment: @LaytonGB  python arrays are row-major, so height is 2 and width is 3

Comment: Why 'x'? Shouldn't it be 'd'? What if it is 3 rows?

Comment: Arrays start at index 0. We can filter that out and shift our result but (0, 2) wouldn't be possible, because your saying that you don't want 0's. So (1, 2) is actually x, or (0, 1) not some unknown combination of the two lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any examples where this doesn't work.

```py
def i2d(r, c, w):
    return r * w + c + 1

def d2i(d, w):
    div = int((d - 1) / w)
    return (div, (d - 1) % w)
```

Comment: Well done, Nice, you can use int() instead of math.floor()

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? Outputs are commented throughout.

```py
grid2 = [['a','b','c'], ['x','y','z']]
height = 2
width = 3
         
def i2d(r = None, c = None):
    a = 1
    if r is not None and c is not None:
        for i in range(height):
            for j in range(width):
                if i == r and j == c:
                    return a
                a += 1
print(i2d(0, 2)) # 3

def d2i(l, d):
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            if d == i2d(i, j):
                return l[i][j]
print(d2i(grid2, 3)) # 'c'
```

Comment: I may think that the logic of i2d may not related to the array itself, I think it is based on mathematical calculations.

Comment: For the provided grid, can you give an example of height and width? Just to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: width = 3 and height=2

Comment: Edited to base calculations off of the width and height parameters.

Comment: Please checkout my question again

Comment: Edited so that the output matches your examples. If there's anything else not-to-spec, please point out the issue.

Comment: He's looking for an algorithm. Not an enumeration

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me :

```
width=3
height=3

def i2d(r,c):
    return r*width + c+1
    
def d2i(d):
    r= int(d/width)
    #cover the h=w case
    if (d%width==0 and width==height):
        r=r-1
    c= d%width-1
    return (r,c)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it would not correct for NxN or HxW where H<W

Comment: If i choose height=2 and width=3 it still works : i just replace 3 by 2 in both function and i get the correct output, i don't get it. Is there any fiddle site where i can share my code ?

Comment: I Will try it now

Comment: It does work for me. And btw you don't need Width and Height. Only the size of each array is necessary. I edited my code

Comment: please check out my update , I think it is dependent on the width and height of the array

Comment: I checked it. If you add if (d%width==0 and width==weight): r=r-1 right after r=int(d/width) It will cover the h=w case and d2i(6) is right. i think, as you have mentioned in your update, the 3 cases have to be covered in both functions